# Filtering and processing computers listed in a CSV file

Tags: performance, beginner, csv, powershell

I am trying to make my script run a lot faster. I have a csv that has about 330k of lines on it that I plan on running my script with and it has been taking an extremely long time. I just did ran the script and it 50 mins to generate the new csv. What the code does is it adds 2 more fields and filters only the administrators and The windows operating systems. Below are before and after pictures of the output.

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
Where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded"
#Modify each line
Foreach ($row in $csv) {
If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
    If ($row."Unique Account Name" -in @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise'))
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}        
}
Else {
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
    If ($row."Account0" -in @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin'))
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}
}
    Write-Host $row."Unique Account Name"
    Write-Host $row."Excluded"    
}

#Export CSV
$csv | Export-Csv U:\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm)-TestOutput1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Can someone help me make my script faster?

Comment: How long is _an extremely long time_? It'd be nice if you also added a sample of your CSV and told _us_ what you are doing with it.

Comment: @t3chb0t I just revised it, it took about 50 mins to generate the csv. The original file is about 33mb. I added pictures as well.

Comment: Ok, 50min for only 330k rows and a 30mb large file is IMO really way too much. Can you explain what the filtering is about? I'm pretty sure this is the bottleneck.

Comment: @t3chb0t In the Name0 column we just want the Administrators so we are filtering just for those. The file comes with a bunch of other names in the Name0 column so we are filtering those first. Then we are also filtering the operating systems that we need, which are provided above. Otherwise they also have servers and we just need the operating systems.

Comment: Take a look at this Stack Overflow question and answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780305/how-to-profiletiming-in-powershell  These are methods you can use to "profile" your code to determine what is the slowest part.

Comment: Try putting a `Measure-Command { ... }` around each of the three sections of the code (that is, the input, processing, and output sections). Once we find out which part is slow, then maybe we can suggest some things to try. The `Write-Host` statements look suspicious to me, by the way. They may be slowing things down.

Comment: @Dangph I noticed the slowest part in it all is the

Comment: Where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","Type0","caption0", "Excluded"

Comment: @BradySprenger, do you mean the `Import-Csv` is faster if you don't include the `Where-Object`and `Select-Object`? It's not clear to me how you determined that that part is the slow part.

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance goes there are a few places to make changes.

### Make better use of the pipeline

You read in the csv to a variable then process. Convert the script to process these records directly. There would be performance increases this way. Insanely brief example...

```
Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' |
   Where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators")}
   Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0" | 
   ForEach-Object {
       # Something happens. 
} | Export-Csv ....
```

### Wasted console output

I cannot imagine you are checking ~1000's of lines of console output. You are wasting processing time but putting that data to console. Remove the `write-host` lines. Even if you have this running as a task.

### Where-Object is slow

This is really easy to use but is not very performance friendly. I can tell you have at least PowerShell 3.0 but if you have at least v4 then you have access to the where and foreach methods of collections. The syntax as you will see is very similar but there should be performance boons here as well. Example:

```
(Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\devices.csv).where({$_.DeviceType -ne "BlackBerry"})
```

I think you are already doing this but order your conditions in order of least likely to most likely. PowerShell will not evaluate the RHS of `-and` if the LHS is already false.

---

I tried to improve the logic in your regex but it was at a cost of performance everytime. As redundant as that string is it seems to be a faster choice given other options.